# org.json.JSONException: No value for custom

Tags: java, android

Guys any help thanks in project i got error like this

**my json data**

`{"time": "1422282109",
"time_pretty": "Mon Jan 26 2015, 6:21am",
"time_total": "10",
"ip_address": "107.5.167.0",
"uid": "1692954453",
"session_id": "1094364389",
"actions": "1",
"total_visits": "2",
"first_visit": {},
"landing_page": "http://clicky.com/blog/",
"web_browser": "Safari 8.0",
"operating_system": "Mac OS X",
"screen_resolution": "1280x800",
"javascript": "1",
"language": "English",
"geolocation": "Macomb, MI, USA",
"country_code": "us",
"latitude": "42.6735",
"longitude": "-82.9165",
"hostname": "comcast.net",
"organization": "Comcast Cable",
"custom": {
"username": "finnllow"
}`

when i tried to access `username`
got error like this

**Error**

`org.json.JSONException: Value {"username":"jprezzi"} at custom of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`

**My code**

```
JSONArray cus = vvObj.getJSONArray(TAG_OBJ_CUSTOM);
    String getUserName = "";
    for (int f = 0; f < cus.length(); f++) {
       JSONObject cud = cus.getJSONObject(f);
       getUserName = cud.getString(TAG_OBJ_USERNAME);
    }
```

i tried direct json object but there is also error

```
org.json.JSONException:no value for custom
```

**Code**

```
JSONObject cutom = vvObj.getJSONObject("custom");
String name = custom.getString("username");
```

**EDIT**
i got my problem solved

the problem is sometimes in  `username`key the value is not set in JSON data for that is used `optString`, using this when value is not present it won't through error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom isn't a `JSONArray`, it is a `JSONObject`. So when you try to convert the `JSONObject` custom to a `JSONArray`, you get an exception. To get the `username` field out of the `custom` object, use:

```
JSONObject cus = vvObj.getJSONObject(TAG_OBJ_CUSTOM);
String getUserName = "";
getUserName = cus.getString(TAG_OBJ_USERNAME);
```

Comment: thanks for the help but now i'm getting error `org.json.JSONException: No value for username`

Comment: It appears as if the object you are parsing doesn't have that key. Have you tried attaching a debugger and seeing what the json object contains? Otherwise, you can check if the main json object has the "custom" key by doing: `if(json.has("custom")){ /* get username here */ }`

Comment: yeah i checked there is no value for some objects thanks for the explain

Comment: @HemanthSTobi glad to help! Let me know if you are in any further need of help. If my answer answers your question, feel free to mark it as the correct answer!